# SVN - How to find all branches where revision was merged into?

Tags: svn

How can I query SVN to find out which branches contain a given commit?
I know this is possible in Git, but what about on SVN?

Comment: I just had a similar issue and for me the question was more “has this been merged into our latest release?” Fortunately, for that `svn propget svn:mergeinfo ^/tags/7.6.4` provides ample information.